# Get The table id in JQuery

Tags: jquery

I have made three html tables with id's are "table1","table2" and "table3". I am able to get the id of first table. How to get Id of all three tables and then show these Id in output using JQuery.
For e.g Table Id's are : "table1" then "table2" and then "table3"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$('table').each(function(){
   alert(this.id);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you're using a selector on some other properties, since I miss the point of getting IDs you already know.
By the way, you can cycle on your selected set with each() and get your Element's IDs.
Example:

```
$('table').each(function() {
  alert( $(this).attr('id') );
}
```